# Show that in the Schroeder-Bernstein Theorem proof the set $X_0$ is the smallest set such that the function h in the proof is bijective

Tags: set-theory

I think basically the question means that if there is a set $X_1$ that works then $X_0 \subset X_1.$ How do I go about doing this?

This is the proof we are using.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Although it is not quite clear from how you wrote the question, you want $X_0$ to be a fixed point of the map $F$, so the question is how to determine $X_0$ so that it is the smallest fixed point. To see this, define sets $C_0,C_1,\dots$ by

- $C_0=\emptyset$,
- $C_1=F(C_0)$,
- $C_2=F(C_1)$,
- etc., that is, $C_{n+1}=F(C_n)$ for all $n$.

Suppose $X$ is a fixed point of $F$. Since $X\supseteq \emptyset=C_0$, monotonicity of $F$ gives us that $C_1=F(C_0)\subseteq F(X)=X$. Similarly, we have that if $C_n\subseteq X$, then $C_{n+1}=F(C_n)\subseteq F(X)=X$. It follows that $X\supseteq \bigcup_n C_n$.

It is now a simple matter to check directly that $\bigcup_n C_n$ is a fixed point of $F$, and therefore $X_0=\bigcup_n C_n$ is the smallest fixed point of $F$.

---

This argument also illustrates a common theme: When looking for fixed points of maps, typically iterations of the map give clues of what these fixed points are. The paper where the fixed point lemma is proved,

> Alfred Tarski, *A lattice-theoretical ﬁxpoint theorem and its applications*, Pacific J. Math., **5** (1955), 285–309. [MR0074376 (17,574d)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=74376),

contains several applications and variants where fixed points are explicitly identified via iterating (perhaps transfinitely) the relevant maps.

Comment: Knaster-Tarski lemma can be applied here?

Comment: Rather than applying the statement of the theorem, which only gives me that there exists a fixed point, without any additional information on its nature, I am directly building the fixed point.

Comment: one more thing, would the fixed point translate to a set? And is the smallest set in the general case $\emptyset?$

Comment: No idea what you mean here.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo:  I could not follow your outline of the proof in that  $\bigcup_n C_n\subset X$, then $X_0 =\bigcup_n C_n$ is the smallest fixed point.  In addition,  $X$ is assumed to be a fixed set, but the outline contains no pointers which help me how this assumption can be proved or verified.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo:  I trust that you tried to give a hint in proving a version of the Knaster-Tarski Lemma.  But I suspect that (of course, I may be wrong) the way $X_0$ is defined above would turn out to be the largest, not the smallest, such fixed set for $F$.  In any case, I still appreciate your post.

Comment: @C.Y.Cheng It is hard to understand what you are saying (for instance, "$X$ is assumed to be a fixed set, but the outline contains no pointers which help me how this assumption can be proved or verified." $X$ is *assumed* to be a fixed point. One does not *prove* one's assumptions). Anyway, $X_0$ is the smallest fixed point of $F$, and my argument establishes that.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Thank you for your comment. You're right and I understand your proof now. Particularly, $F(\cup_n C_n) =\cup_n F(C_n)=\cup_n C_{n-1}=X_0$, so $X_0$ is a smallest fixed set. Is it practical to use this definition to find $X_0$, given the function?